# Detect OS from Bash script and notify user

Tags: string, bash, system, uname

Using bash, I want to find the operating system and notify the user. I tried:

```
OS='uname -s'
echo "$OS"
if [ "$OS" == 'Linux' ]; then
    echo "Linux"
else 
    echo "Not Linux"
fi
```

I just get

```
uname -s 
Not Linux
```

on the terminal, which is wrong. How do I correctly set the string to what uname returns?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rather than single quotes, you probably meant to use backticks:

```
OS=`uname -s`
```

but you really want

```
OS=$(uname -s)
```

Also, rather than an if statment, which will eventually become an if/else series, you might consider using case:

```
case $( uname -s ) in
Linux) echo Linux;;
*)     echo other;;
esac
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is the first time I've ever noticed the difference between a ` and a ' :D

Comment: That's just one reason `$()` is superior :)

Comment: Oblig. quoting suggestion: `case "$(uname -s)"` in case the output contains spaces (although perhaps that is exceedingly unlikely).

Comment: @chepner.  The quotes are not necessary, even if the output contains spaces.  `$()` is a quoting mechanism, so putting it in double quotes is redundant.  Consider: a='foo bar'; case $( echo foo bar ) in; $a):;; esac

Comment: `$()` only quotes when used immediately to the right of `=` in a variable assignment.  Try `/bin/ls $(date)` to see the lack of quoting by `$()`.  This probably doesn't affect the answer given above much, since `uname -s` almost always outputs a single word (without spaces).

Comment: $() doesn't perform the quoting at all. Bash does not word-split on the right side of a variable assignment.

Comment: ... Nor on the argument to `case` which is why you don't need quotes there.

Comment: Indeed, the expression "`$()` is a quoting mechanism" is complete nonsense.  Bash doesn't word split the RHS of an assignment or the argument of `case`[

Answer (score 2):

This will return the OS as requested - note that `uname` is not necessarily available on all OSes so it's not part of this answer.

```
case "$OSTYPE" in
  linux*)   echo "linux" ;;
  darwin*)  echo "mac" ;; 
  msys*)    echo "windows" ;;
  solaris*) echo "solaris" ;;
  bsd*)     echo "bsd" ;;
  *)        echo "unknown" ;;
esac
```

Comment: -1 There is nothing Bash-specific here but it also does not solve the OP's problem at all.

Comment: his question says "Using bash, I want to find the operating system and notify the user" `uname` is not OS agnostic - it won't work on some OSes. This solution should work on bash on most. You're correct that it's not bash specific so i've adjusted the answer.

Comment: "$OSTYPE", distinguishes between android phones and full Linux installations.